# When running "import torch" in Jupiter notebook, I am getting "No module named "torch"

Tags: python, terminal

So..
when I open my terminal on my mac (using .zsh) and I input the command:  `pip3 install torch torchvision`

the output contains:
`Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.9.0)`
`Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from torch) (3.7.4.3)`

I think I need to change the location of my pip to a new path maybe?  I'm not sure where to move my pip to though or how exactly to do this, to fix my issue.

Comment: Are you running your jupiter notebook in the same enviroment where pip is installing (/usr/local/lib/python3.8...) or another? If another activate that enviroment in a terminal and pip will install torch in that enviroment.

Comment: I think my jupiter notebook is in a different environment than pip, so I think you are right, that is the issue.  In regards to your solution, do you mind explaining your recommendation?  And how I would implement it?

Comment: When you execute your Jupiter notebook, ensure the python environment is what you expect. Look up the term shebang line if it's new to you. Then you know what '#!/usr/bin/env python3' is for.

Comment: Hm, are there any other thoughts as to how to put my jupyter notebook into the same environment as my Pip installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `conda` try to use it.

1. Check **jupiter notebook** via conda:

   `conda list`
2. Install **jupiter notebook**:

   `conda install jupyter`
3. Try:

   `conda update conda`

   `conda install mkl=2018`

last ref: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/issues-installing-pytorch-for-os-x-with-conda/11496